# xampp localhost phpmyadmin Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

I am getting two errors when I try to go to my phpmyadmin localhost

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong...here is my config code...

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = ''; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

/* 
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/* 
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'socket'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
/* Select mysqli if your server has it */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
/* User for advanced features */
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pmauser';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'pmapass';
/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';

/* 
 * End of servers configuration
 */

/*
 * Directories for saving/loading files from server
 */
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';

?>
```

I notice a lot of code is commented out, should I un-commented it?

Comment: are you sure that you need password to connect with your database?? if you dont need password do this $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';

Comment: this error comes while connecting to database. So try to echo the connection string details to debug (to know what values its taking to connect are the correct values or not).

Comment: Have you gone to the default xampp page and gone through the security screens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't change anything , put as it was there , just open your xampp and try to access mysql  from shell **cd c://xampp/mysql/bin** after this write 
**mysql**
and click enter it will open your databases

Comment: Isn't this just access from the command line? Where does phpmyadmin fit into this?

Answer (score 17):

try these step

1. Open config.inc.php file in the phpmyadmin directory
2. Find line 21: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''`
3. Change it to: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'your_password';`
4. Restart XAMPP

[here is full description  with image](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/error-1045-phpmyadmin/)

Answer (score 7):

After spending so much time what i came know is.

Just use this setting-> Open config.inc.php file in the phpmyadmin directory

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;  
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

You should have one user with @localhost host name. Now phpmyadmin will ask you for password. if you provide correct password,You will be able to login.

Answer (score 2):

Change the following line under your config code from

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password';
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

Answer (score 2):

If the XAMPP->MySQL Port was changed, (default port is 3306) the new port must be added to the phpMyAdmin file:

[xampp phpmyadmin access denied error(#2002)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22971248/xampp-phpmyadmin-access-denied-error2002)

`C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php`

from:
`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';`
to :
`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3308';`

Answer (score 1):

Hey if none of troubleshoots are working for you then I have a solution because none of the solution worked for me and only these two step worked.

Step 1 ->
go to C:\xampp and right click on xampp-control.exe and click on properties go to compatibility and check the run this program as administrator and click apply:

[image: properties setting of xampp-control.exe]'image'

Step 2 -> (MOST IMP STEP)
Sometimes no matter how much you try to change the port number in config file or in other phpMyAdmin file XAMPP will listen to some specific port which you can see here:

[image: XAMPP snapshot]'image'

even if the config file of MySQL says some other port but xampp will listen to this port only and just see this port number and go to C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin then go in config.inc.php and write

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = 2023;
```

remember 2023 is the port which was showing me in the xampp control panel it could be something else for you.
I am sure this will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to login to the database from command line using the same authentication credentials. This way you verify that you are really using the correct authentication credentials like username and password. If you fail on command line the problem is not with phpmyadmin but with your database engine setup.

Comment: You need the mysql client installed. It comes with a man page. But the general usage is: `mysql -u <our-user-name> -p [RETURN]`. If you want to access a database server on a different system you must make sure you have network access to the servers port, usually port 3306 for mysql. But as said: read the man page or the mysql documentation. It is all explained in there.