# XAMPP MySQL password setting (Can not enter in PHPMYADMIN)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

**Firstly:** I am cannot entering  PHPMYADMIN  at *"localhost:80/phpmyadmin/"*. Because when I install MySQL server mysql-5.5.36 with Username :root and Password : HamdunSoft . After that when I enter localhost:80/phpmyadmin/ it show me a message like below .

*"**Error  MySQL said: Documentation 
1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)**
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server."*

Now I want enter my Phpmyadmin though  I have setup two MySQL server one in xampp, another mysql-5.5.36. I have searched it in net but the content was not helpful sufficiently. How can I set the password in xampp before login in phpmyadmin .

**Another different issue is:**   XAMPP Apache server was saying : port 80 is being used by some one. I solved it by stopping Skype. But again having this types of problem. I think like Skype another software is using port 80. I want to use any port with Apache as I wish. It may be port 80 or 81 or 82. If any other process is using my desired port I want to replace that and give that port to Apache.

Comment: Kindly check this one. I think so this help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33265615/2875455

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**First Issue:** 
You want to run Mysql server from Mysql and from Xampp also want to browse phpmyadmin so that you can operate database.Then follow the rules:

From **"Xampp/phpmyadmin"** directory in *config.inc.php* file find the below code. And follow the given instructions below. I have tried like this and I was successful to run both localhost/phpMyAdmin on browser, MySQL Command prompt as well as MySQL query browser.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']    = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']         = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']     = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']  = 'user_name/root';   
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']  = 'passwaord';
```

And replace the above each statement  with the below each corresponding code.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']    = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']         = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']     = 'Muhammad Ashikuzzaman';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']  = 'root';   
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']  = 'Muhammad Ashikuzzaman';
```

**Second Issue:**
**Way 1 :** You can quit Skype first. And when Apche server is started then again you can run Skype. If you want to run Apache in another port then replace in xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf "ServerName localhost:80" by "ServerName localhost:81" At line 184. After that even it may not work. Then replace

```
#Listen 0.0.0.0:80
#Listen [::]:80
Listen 80
```

by

```
#Listen 0.0.0.0:81
#Listen [::]:81
Listen 81
```

at line 45

**Way 2 :** If you want to use port 80. Then follow this. In Windows 8 “World Wide Publishing Service is using this port and stopping this service will free the port 80 and you can connect Apache using this port. To stop the service go to the “Task manager –> Services tab”, right click the “World Wide Publishing Service” and stop. If you don't find there then go to "Run > services.msc" and again find there and right click the “World Wide Publishing Service” and stop.

If you didn't find “World Wide Publishing Service” there then go to "Run>>resmon.exe>> Network Tab>>Listening Ports" and see which process is using port 80.

And from "Overview>>CPU" just Right click on that process and click "End Process Tree". If that process is system that might be a critical issue.

Answer (score 39):

Find the below code in xampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']  = 'user_name/root';   
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']  = 'passwaord';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']    = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']         = 'user_name/root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']     = 'password';
```

Replace each statement above with the corresponding entry below:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']  = 'root';   
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']  = 'xxxx';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']    = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']         = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']     = 'xxxx';
```

Doing this caused localhost/phpmyadmin in the browser and the MySQL command prompt to work properly.

Answer (score 6):

1.open your xampp dir ( c:/xampp )

2.to phpMyadmin dir [C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin]

3.open [ config.inc.php ] file with any text editor

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config'; //replace 'config' to ‘cookie’
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true; //change ‘true’ to ‘false’.
```

last : save the file .

here is a video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ElaYZFwJdfc) in case you want to see it in Action [ [click Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ElaYZFwJdfc) ]

Answer (score 1):

If you can not authenticate via the web interface (localhost/phpmyadmin/) then try change authentication type to cookie.

> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';

Answer (score 1):

If all the other answers do not work for you check the `config.inc.php` for the following:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

…and add the port of MySQL set in your XAMPP as shown below:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3307';
```

Stop MySQL from XAMPP and restart MySQL.

Open a fresh page for `http://localhost:8012/phpmyadmin/` and check.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old question but I am just going to place this here:

To prevent skype from using port 80 and port 443, open the Skype window, then click on the **Tools menu** and select **Options**.

Click on the **Advanced ta**b, and go to the **Connection sub-tab**.

Uncheck the checkbox for Use port 80 and 443 as an alternative for additional incoming connections option.

Click on the **Save button** and then **restart Skype**.

After you restart skype, skype wont use port 88 or 443 anymore.

Hope this might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL multiple instances present on Ubuntu.

step 1 : if it's listed as installed, you got it. Else you need to get it.

sudo ps -A | grep mysql

step 2 : remove the one MySQL

sudo apt-get remove mysql

sudo service mysql restart

step 3 : restart lamp

sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart

Answer (score 0):

user: root

password: [blank]

XAMPP v3.2.2