# Getting started with xampp

Tags: windows, apache, tomcat, xampp, port

so I've just downloaded xampp on my laptop (Windows 10). When trying to start it there seems to be a few problems which I'm not too sure how to fix being unfamiliar with xampp. Please let me know what I need to do, thanks.

Note: See  pic attached[XAMPP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Itdrc.jpg)

Comment: You should change port number . Find something here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port

Comment: Stop the process listening on port 8080 or Switch the port in Server.xml of your tomcat

Comment: The error message on that image could not be clearer ...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by changing the port that Skype was using, it happened to be the same as XAMPP was trying to use.

You can see the discussion with the solution that helped me in the link below

Open Skype.

Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connection.

Disable the "Use port 80 and 443 for alternatives for incoming connections"

Sign Out and Close all Skype windows. Try restarting your Apache.

[XAMPP MySQL password setting (Can not enter in PHPMYADMIN)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22333581/xampp-mysql-password-setting-can-not-enter-in-phpmyadmin)