# Access Denied in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I can't open my phpmyadmin. Access denied error is coming. I Tried  to stop mysql service from terminal and restarting my lampp but it didn't help

[image: phpmyadmin]

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339416/xamp-localhost-phpmyadmin-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-passw

Comment: i checked  this but it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

**Step1** : Open `phpMyAdmin/librarires/config.inc.php`

**Step2** : `Change $cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] = ''` to `$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] = 'localhost/phpmyadmin/';`

**Step3** : `change $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost'` to `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'Localhost';`

**Step4** : change `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''` to `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'type your password here';`

**Step5** : Reboot `MySql`

Answer (score 0):

As per your screen shot It seems you are trying to connect local mysql server and not passing root user's password. Please again try with user as root and password as you set for root and share if there is any error.

Also make sure first that mysql is running on server.